# CKEditor copy/paste action with background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I have multiple edit areas with CKEditor in inline mode, and in copy/paste action when paste is selected, it applies an automatic white background to the text. To prevent this from happening i have defined the following code in my config.js:

```
`config.disallowedContent = '*{background*}';`
```

And is result of copy/paste from other area with CKEditor (inside my application):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyqJp.png

But with this code the option of BGcolor in the toolbar disappears, not allowing the user to set the background color in the text.

- Does there exist some solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the library to the latest version. CKEditor 4.5.x introduces [`CKEDITOR.config.pasteFilter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter), that helps you filter out the garbage produced by the **browsers** (particularly Blink/Webkit) on paste. You can configure it or simply leave the default value

> `` Defaults to: 'semantic-content' in Chrome and Safari and `null` in other browsers ``

See the difference in live example ([4.4.8](http://codepen.io/anowodzinski/pen/EjQOaE) vs [4.5.1](http://codepen.io/anowodzinski/pen/bdLQbV)). Best with Google Chrome.

Comment: Note also that since version 4.5.0 CKEditor puts the selected content on copy/cut/dragstart to the clipboard itself on browser on which it is possible. And since CKEditor is focused on semantic content (while e.g. Chrome on creating garbage) content put in the clipboard does not contain any unwanted styles. So if you copy between editors, you won't even need the paste filter.